# Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Then which of the following statements are true?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $T:X \to X $ be a continuous function satisfying $\inf_{n\in \mathbb N}d(T^n(x),T^n(y))\neq 0$ for every distinct $x$ and $y$. Then which of the following statements are true?

1. $T:X \to X $ is one-one.
2. $T:X \to X $ is not one-one.
3. Image of $T:X \to X $ is closed.
4. If $X$ is finite, then $T$ is onto.

**My Try**

$\inf_{n\in \mathbb N}d(T^n(x),T^n(y))\neq 0$. So, $n=1$ $x\neq y, d(T^1(x),T^1(y))\neq 0$. Hence, $T$ is one-one. So, prtion 1 is true. option 2 is false. Let $f:\mathbb [0,1]\to [0,1]$, $f(x)=x$, which indicates that image $T$ is closed. If $X$ is finite, If $T$ is injective, then $T$ must be onto. So, option (1),(3),(4) are correct. How do I give formal proof?

Comment: $T$ is continuous, $X$ is compact, so $T(X)$ is compact hence closed

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for 1), 20 and 4) are correct but you cannot prove that 3) is true by just giving an example. Since $X$ is compact and $T$ is continuous the image of $T$ is compact, hence closed in $X$.